# Executing a Gitlab pipeline from receiving a webhook

Tags: linux, server, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

I'm running a local gitlab server (omnibus) and I have a company internal repo (set up through Rhodecode). I'm trying to get Gitlab to trigger a pipeline upon receiving a webhook from our Repo once there is a push done to our repo. Then have a python script parse the JSON data from the webhook, and then depending on the message in the commit, trigger a test or not. I'm doing this all on VM's on our local server. The Gitlab is on a linux machine.
I've hunted for information on Gitlab receiving a webhook and triggering a pipeline event, but haven't got anywhere with it yet. I've tried the token generation, and checking the push webhook post on linux to see if I'm receiving any data, to no avail. Today I'm going to be comparing log files to see if it's logging the webhook presence and then go from there.

Answer (score 4):

### Gitlab Side

Create a [Trigger Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#create-a-trigger-token) ,
then [follow the "trigger a pipeline" howto](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#trigger-a-pipeline)

Example:

```bash
    curl --request POST \
    --form token=<token> \
    --form ref=<ref_name> \
    "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/trigger/pipeline"
```

OR on a specific ref_name(with a branch or tag name, like main):

```bash
    curl --request POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/trigger/pipeline?token=<token>&ref=<ref_name>"
```

### RhodeCode side:

- Your version should be at least `4.17.3`
- [people saw problems between https and ssh push behaviour before this version](https://community.rhodecode.com/t/push-through-http-doesn-t-trigger-webhook/341/3)
- [RhodeCode has documentation for their webhook system](https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/integrations/webhook.html),
  also this page mentions

  ```
  Starting from 4.8.0 also repository extra fields can be used.
  A format to use them is ${extra:field_key}. 
  It’s usefull to use them to specify custom repo only parameters.
  Some of the variables like ${pull_request_id} will be replaced only in the pull request related events.
  ```

  so see if you really send the same fields
- with debug log enabled , the log should have some lines containing `DEBUG [rhodecode.integrations.types.webhook]`

### Debugging Webhook

- try to use a testing endpoint like e.g. [pustreq.com](https://putsreq.com/) to see if your outgoing webhook sends what you want

Regards

Comment: So I took your advice and can activate a pipeline using the curl --request POST " ..."

However I still can't get the webhook to send and activate. I can see the webhook coming in on the production.log file, but it does not execute the pipeline.

Comment: | did you add runners to our gitlab instance ?  pipelines wiil not run unless you do so | what do you mean by "send and activate" ? | is your gitlab-ci  file named " .gitlab-ci.yml" ? | do pipelines run when triggered through web UI ? |

Comment: yes, I can run pipelines both manually on the web UI, as well as through the curl trigger on linux terminal. What I can't get, is it to trigger using a webhook my repo sends out.

Comment: what do you mean by "sends out" ..

if you want another repo to trigger you would need a .gitlab-ci.yml with a docker image that supports curl ( or install it in the script ) and then make it run the curl command on push

Comment: I have a local repo, I have that repo set up to send a webhook to my gitlab server with the trigger information to activate a pipeline. I can send the exact same webhook with a python scrip and it triggers the gitlab pipeline fine. The Rhodecode webhook does not trigger the pipeline. The webhook URLs are the exact same.

Comment: ( added information to the answer , please review your rhodeocde version , if there is a difference between ssh / https pushing  and the documentation on the custom hook fields )